# Integrate $\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

For what values of $x$ is this valid?

$$\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{a}\tanh^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+C$$

I think the anwer should be $-a<x<a$ because of the domain of $tanh^{-1}$. Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: do you know that $\frac{1}{(x-b)(x-c)} = \frac{1}{b-c} \left(\frac{1}{x-b}- \frac{1}{x-c}\right)$ ?

Comment: @ImreVegh Yes. Also because $\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}=\infty$ at $x=\pm a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense to divide the problem into finding an antiderivative in the three intervals $I_{-}=(-\infty,-a)$, $I_0=(-a,a)$ and $I_+=(a,\infty)$ (I assume, which is not restrictive, that $a>0$).

With a simple substitution, the problem for $I_{-}$ can be reduced to the problem for $I_+$.

If we are in $I_0$, we can make the substitution $x=a\tanh t$, so the integral becomes
$$
\int \frac{1}{a^2(1-\tanh^2t)}a(1-\tanh^2t)\,dt=\frac{t}{a}+C_0
$$
and so an antiderivative is
$$
\frac{1}{a}\operatorname{artanh}\frac{x}{a}+C_0
$$

If we are in $I_+$ the substitution above cannot be done, but we can do instead $x=a/\tanh t$ and we get
$$
\int\frac{1}{a^2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\tanh^2t}\right)}
\left(-\frac{a}{\tanh^2t}(1-\tanh^2t)\right)dt
=\frac{t}{a}+C_+
$$
so the antiderivative is
$$
\frac{1}{a}\operatorname{artanh}\frac{a}{x}+C_+
$$

In summary, the most general antiderivative is
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{a}\operatorname{artanh}\dfrac{a}{x}+C_- & x<-a \\[6px]
\dfrac{1}{a}\operatorname{artanh}\dfrac{x}{a}+C_0 & -a<x<a \\[6px]
\dfrac{1}{a}\operatorname{artanh}\dfrac{a}{x}+C_+ & x>a
\end{cases}
$$

Of course, rewriting the integral as
$$
\frac{1}{2a}\int\left(\frac{1}{a-x}+\frac{1}{a+x}\right)dx
$$
is easier.

Comment: But I thought that $tanh^{-1}(x)$ is not defined for $x>1$? How come you can still define it?

Comment: @ImreVégh If $x>a$, then $0<a/x<1$< so $\operatorname{artanh}(a/x)$ is defined. If $x<-a$, then $-1<a/x<0$.

Comment: Ah, I see in your answer you took the reciprocal, I missed that!